# Alter table with foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, alter

I have three tables.

```
Person (id, FirstName, LastName, BirthDate)
Contact (id, contact, type)
PersonContact( Person_id, Contact_id )
```

As you can see that Person_id is comming from Person table in PersonContact table
And Contact_id is comming from Contact table in PersonContact table

I want to write a query that should relate Person_id column of PersonContact table with id column of Person Table as foreign key.

And Contact_id column of PersonContact with id column of Contact table as foreign key

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to add foreign key constraints to PersonContact right?  So you can't add a record to PersonContact unless the referenced records exist in Person and Contact?

Comment: @Kendrick: Yes you are right..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should answer the problem

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `person_contact` (
  `contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `person_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`contact_id`,`person_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


ALTER TABLE `person_contact`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `person_contact_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `person_contact_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `contact` (`id`);
```

Comment: It gives me following error: `#1005 - Can't create table 'chdp.#sql-305_45' (errno: 150) (<a href="server_engines.php?engine=InnoDB&amp;page=Status&amp;token=094ae6431f26118a5ceb3cf8c4dea1e4">Details...</a>)`

Comment: In order to have a relational engine (foreign keys and integrity constraints), Your mysql server must have innodb engine activated.
And the tables you create must use this engine(by default mysql uses myisam engine which is not relational).
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person_contact (
  contact_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  person_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (contact_id,person_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`
Specify `ENGINE=InnoDB` as above for each tables

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

```
alter PersonContact add foreign key(PersonID) references Person(ID)
```

To select, you do:

```
select *
    from Person
        inner join PersonContact on(Person.ID=PersonContact.PersonID)
```

Comment: Can anyone confirm if this works? When I try it, it complains that `Key column 'PersonID' Does not exist in the table`

Comment: Does it exist in the table?  In the case above, his columns were named differently, and that can lead to confusion.  Also, you have to have the innodb engine enabled, and applied to the table.  I'm inclined to take the error message at face value though.  If you're still having a problem after double checking, post a new question with your specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my $0.02 worth of advise in terms of T-SQL

Select FirstName, LastName, BirthDate
from Person p
join PersonContact pc ON
p.id= pc.Person_id

Select Contact, type
From Contact c 
join PersonContact pc 
ON c.id= pc.Person_id